# neo4j reverse proxy config for apache

Tags: apache, neo4j

Can someone provide me with Apache reverse proxy config for neo4j. Specifically the one to connect to the Database.

This is my current Apache reverse config:

```
Redirect /neo4j /neo4j/

ProxyPass /neo4j/ https://hostname:7473/browser/

ProxyPassReverse /neo4j/ https://hostname:7473/browser/
```

and on the backend server where neo4j is installed and running, this is the only port thats listening

`tcp6       0      0 :::7473              :::*                 LISTEN      21202/java`

I can load the neo4j page from the web, but when I try to connect to the DB, I am getting ServiceUnavailable: Failed to fetch.

This is installed version - neo4j-3.5.0-1.noarch

Any help will be much appreciated